# 1 bitcoin deposited into electrum

Tags: transactions

about 4 days ago I received 1 bitcoin from localbitcoins.com since then in history it says.....unverified + 1 confirmation. I have switched servers as per forum advice and so far nothing has changed. I want to deposit to another address but am terrified to do it. Please note I am no techie, I copied and pasted my deposit address for this transaction on ?a blockchain thing and it is there, how can speed up the confirmation to get my history to say verified, do I have to donate some coin to the blockchain or what? Please if you can help do so in the most simplistic terms only.....thank you

Comment: also input the the transaction hash/address and it shows 856 confirmations so why is it still unverified in my wallet history?

Comment: under network the protocol selected is....ssl and in the proxy header...none...is selected

Answer (score 1):

This is a common problem with electrum and nothing for you to worry about. As long as the transaction has confirmed in the blockchain it means that the coins are yours. Usually restarting electrum "fixes" this. Try restarting it a few times.

Comment: Thank you so much for responding, when I look at the block chain all is fine but this is my first coin transaction and I did not want to send then anywhere for fear this would get complicated if there was an existing problem. I did open and close the client numerous times and did shut down as well. At least  now I know that if the block chain info is good and there are many confirmations all is in order.

Comment: @Nancy yes well you need a) confirmations in the blockchain b) ownership of the private key behind the address. I am assuming the address with the confirmations is the exact one in your electrum wallet? Also this is not a watch-only wallet i.e. it does NOT say watch only in the electrum window title bar? If the answer is yes to both questions then you are good.

Comment: thank you again, I have exactly one bit coin and I tried to send it to another deposit address but it says insufficient funds, please help me again if you would I don't understand the window shows the fee required and I assumed it would be taken during the transaction and what is remaining will go to the deposit address. I have no other transactions I traded cash for one bit coin...help please...thank you!

Comment: This isn't a good place for technical support. I suggest you create an account at bitcointalk.org forums and post about this problem there.